# ActionBar to my PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, action

How can I add ActionBar to my non ActionBaryActivity classes? I use that Material like appcompact theme
and now if I make a "PreferenceActivity" there is no action bar.(i would like to use this:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PreferenceFragments in a ActionBarActivity instead.
PreferenceActivity is deprecated anyway.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html